# These names disappear arraylist, how to make them stay in place?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, arraylist

The problem is that the names are set separately Arraylist, but when I save them they disappear as shown on the [gif](https://www.cyberforum.ru/attachments/1233325d1615305375)

```java
private ArrayList<String> pinNames = new ArrayList<String>();
int i = 0;

if (i < pinNames.size() && pinNames.get(i) != null )
{
    String p = pinNames.get(i++);
    canvas.drawText("" + p, vX, vY, paint);
}
```

Comment: You're not looping over the list. You just process the very first item in the list. I guess you need a `for` loop instead of the `if` statement.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comments to my other answer, here is another attempt:

```java
private ArrayList<String> pinNames = new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayList<PointF> sPin = new ArrayList<PointF>();

// assert pinNames.size() == sPin.size()

for(int i = 0; i < pinNames.size(); i++)
{
    String pinName = pinNames.get(i);
    PointF pinPosition = sPin.get(i);

    if(pinName != null && pinPosition != null)
    {
        PointF vPin = sourceToViewCoord(pinPosition);
        float vX = vPin.x - (pinBitmap.getWidth() / 2);
        float vY = vPin.y - pinBitmap.getHeight();

        canvas.drawText("" + pinName, vX, vY, paint);
    }
}
```

Comment: Same problem, vX and vY -responsible for pin location

Comment: sorry, I found a mistake of mine: change `PointF vPin = sourceToViewCoord(point);` to `PointF vPin = sourceToViewCoord(pinPosition);` Does it help?

Answer (score 0):

To iterate over the list, use a `foreach`-Loop:

```java
private ArrayList<String> pinNames = new ArrayList<String>();
for(String pinName : pinNames)
{
    if(pinName != null)
    {
        canvas.drawText("" + pinName, vX, vY, paint);
    }
}
```

Comment: In a loop like this, I get names on top of each other

Comment: Which values are you using for `vX` and `vY`?

Comment: for (PointF point : sPin) {
            if (point != null && pinBitmap != null ) {

                    PointF vPin = sourceToViewCoord(point);
                    float vX = vPin.x - (pinBitmap.getWidth() / 2);
                    float vY = vPin.y - pinBitmap.getHeight(); }

Comment: without context, it's hard to answer. What is `sPin` for example? Try to put some context in your question's code.

Comment: For each pinName you have to pass its correct (`vX`, `vY`)-position into the `drawText()` method.

Comment: private ArrayList<PointF> sPin = new ArrayList<>();

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure from this solution but i think you should try this :

```
private ArrayList<String> pinNames = new ArrayList<String>();
int i = 0;

while (i < pinNames.size() && pinNames.get(i) != null ){
String p = pinNames.get(i);
canvas.drawText("" + p, vX, vY, paint);
i++;
}
```

try this and tell me if it works .

Comment: sorry for that bro :(